# Accessing localhost server(xampp) from another one(phonegap) on same pc

Tags: cordova, xampp, ip, localhost, port

I have on my machine XAMPP running through port 80, and now I'm running a PhoneGap app in port 3000. I'd like to request info from the PhoneGap app to my xampp server, but I don't have any answer from it. I don't know if I have permission problems, since no error shows up, but I tried changing httpd.conf and httpf-xampp.conf files with no result. I tried requesting info from 192.168.0.103:80 and 192.168.0.103 being it my local ip. Example: `<img scr="192.168.0.103/myserver/images/myimage.jpg>` or even

```
$.post('192.168.0.103:80/myserver/handler.php', { 'i' : x })
```

and neither give any results. Is there some step to access the server that I don't know of? I'd really appreciate any directions.

Edit: I have just tried to run the Phonegap server on another pc. The pc can access the xampp server through the browser, but the phonegap server can't. Is it possible for xampp to be blocking requests from port 3000? If so, what can I do?

Comment: can you manually load this link in a mobile browser and check whether the image is being displayed.

Comment: Yes I did that from the server pc browser, IOS, windows phone and android mobiles browsers and phonegap developer app. Same result for all of them, no result from the xampp server. For some reason the phonegap server is not able to access it..

Comment: Oh sorry I think I missundertood your question. Loading 192.168.0.103/myserver/images/myimage.jpg on the mobile browser does display the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. It was actually pretty dumb. 
Instead of using `$.post('192.168.0.103/myserver/handler.php', { 'i' : x })`
to access the server I just used `$.post('http://192.168.0.103:80/myserver/handler.php', { 'i' : x })` and it worked.